# 2checkout payment with billing address

Tags: payment-gateway, 2checkout

I am experiencing an issue (may be). The issue is that when I give billing address with credit card information to create sale. The sale is processed successfully. BUT, when I skip the billing address the`Authorization Failed` is returned.

Is it mandatory to give billing address with credit card information to create sale?

I am doing it with ajax call from my application.

Answer (score 2):

The billing address is required for all sales. This is a requirement of our banking partners for address verification.

Comment: It required also for the invoice, you need to let the user fill the next parameters in you application, then send them: country, card_holder_name, street_address, city, state, zip, phone. The phone is not required but if you using the Inline Checkout method (iframe) they will let the user fill it in the popup iframe, so I prefer to send it.

Comment: Correct, in my test environment I like to pass it through as a hidden parameter. We do have merchants doing this as well with the default 2Checkout phone number to create one less field for the customer to answer. Although this may cause confusion for the merchant if they need to contact the customer via phone at any point.

Comment: Well, as I discovered while creating [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/36807292/105539), billing address indeed is a requirement. If my guess is right that @2CO_Integrations is someone actually working at 2Checkout, then that pretty much nails that answer shut -- billing address required.